# Can't show a list of api returned items

Tags: java, android

I have tried to show a list of items returned from my database, using an api and it works fine in the browser, I can also return a single item without any problems, trying to return a whole list and fit it into Java code causes a lot of issues to me. My code got really messed up, and I am not sure where the problem is, but my guess is, it cannot store the returned values properly.

MainPageActivity:

```
public class MainPageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);

        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListListaEvenata);

        if(EventiLista.getListaEvenata()==null) {
            postaviEvente();
        }

        listView.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                if(EventiLista.getListaEvenata()!=null)
                return EventiLista.getListaEvenata().size();

                else return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return EventiLista.getListaEvenata().get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


                final Eventi x = EventiLista.getListaEvenata().get(position);

                final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.eventistavka, parent, false);

                TextView Naziv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.EventNaziv);

                TextView Opis = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.OpisEventa);

                Naziv.setText(x.Naziv);

                Opis.setText(x.Opis);

                return null;
            }
        });
    }

    protected void postaviEvente() {
        EventiApi.GetEvente(this, new MyRunnable<List<Eventi>>() {


            @Override
            public void run(List<Eventi> result) {
                EventiLista.setListaEvenata(result);
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is also my EventiApi class, probably the one that causes issues:

```
public class EventiApi {
public static List<Eventi> listEventi = EventiLista.getListaEvenata();
    public static List<Eventi> GetEvente(final Context context, final MyRunnable<List<Eventi>> onSuccess) {
        if(listEventi==null) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Eventi>>() {


            @Override
            protected List<Eventi> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(Config.url + "api/Eventi");

                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();


                try {
                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);

                    InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

                    String strJson = convertStreamToString(inputStream);

                    Eventi x = MyGson.build().fromJson(strJson, Eventi.class);

                    listEventi.add(x);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("HttpManager", e.getMessage());

                    EventiLista.setListaEvenata(null);

                }
                return listEventi;
            }


            protected void onPostExecute(List<Eventi> rezultat) {
                if (rezultat == null)
                    Toast.makeText(MyApp.getContext(), "Greska u komunikaciji sa serverom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else {
                    onSuccess.run(rezultat);
                }

            }
        }.execute();


    }
    return listEventi;
    }
    public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean flag = false;
        for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
            result.append(flag ? newLine : "").append(line);
            flag = true;
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Also here's my MyRunnable interface:

```
public interface MyRunnable<T> {

    void run(T result);
}
```

And my EventiLista helper class:

```
public class EventiLista {
    private static List<Eventi> listaEvenata;

    public static List<Eventi> getListaEvenata() {
        return listaEvenata;
    }

    public static void setListaEvenata(List<Eventi> listaEvenata) {
        EventiLista.listaEvenata = listaEvenata;
    }
}
```

MyGson:

```
public class MyGson {
    public static Gson build()
    {
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        builder.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Any help or ideas are highly appreciated, thank you all for your time!

It should show the returned values in my list but the app just breaks.

Here's a part of a logcat:

```
Process: com.example.evente, PID: 6151
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:353)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:224)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:888)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:853)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:802)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:774)
        at com.example.evente.api.EventiApi$1.doInBackground(EventiApi.java:46)
        at com.example.evente.api.EventiApi$1.doInBackground(EventiApi.java:29)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:385)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:213)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:888) 
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:853) 
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:802) 
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:774) 
        at com.example.evente.api.EventiApi$1.doInBackground(EventiApi.java:46) 
        at com.example.evente.api.EventiApi$1.doInBackground(EventiApi.java:29) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: Provide data what you got in response `String strJson = convertStreamToString(inputStream);`

Answer (score 0):

Response you are getting in `String strJson = convertStreamToString(inputStream);` is `JsonArray` and you are converting it into Model Object using `Eventi x = MyGson.build().fromJson(strJson, Eventi.class);`

That's why it throws exception `IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY`

Comment: Thank you, I have added this part now:

 `String strJson = convertStreamToString(inputStream);


                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    Type type = new TypeToken<List<Eventi>>() {
                    }.getType();
                    List<Eventi> listEventi = gson.fromJson(strJson, type);`

And now I'm getting this error:

`Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2020-08-20T00:00:00"`

Comment: I also have a MyGson helper class, I'll edit it into the post.

Comment: Provide data what you got in response `String strJson = convertStreamToString(inputStream);`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Retrofit for HTTP requests
https://square.github.io/retrofit/